# Why is a table re-rendering moving table data outside of the table?

Tags: html, jsf, tomcat, richfaces

I have a JSF file that has an html table in it. The table is surrounded by `<a4j:outputPanel></a4j:outputPanel>` tags.

The table set up is like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Inside the first `<td></td>` of the first row there are 2 `div` elements. When I was using the page I clicked an `<a4j:commandButton>` that rerendered the page and I noticed that the second and third `<td>` in the first row were moving to their own row below the first. I checked the source code and the 2 divs that were in the first `<td>` were no longer in the table at all and were moved to before the `<table>` tag and there were now only 2 `<td>` elements in the first `<tr>`. To test it more I made another `<a4j:commandButton>` that does nothing except rerender the `<a4j:outputPanel>` that the table is in and it was still happening. I was able to fix it but putting an empty table row before the first. This is a workaround but I would like to know why it was happening in the first place. Anyone know?

I am using a tomcat 6 server if it makes a difference.

Comment: Rather than trying to explain it you could just show relevant parts of the actual code. JSF doesn't parse the HTML, I'd expect the elements are being moved on client side. Check the server response to see if the HTML is correct there.

Comment: If it was client side the rerender wouldn't be what's causing the change

Comment: Unless you're reloading the entire page client-side code is what's making the rerender happen.

Comment: There is no client side code running. I'm pretty sure it's a bug in the version of Richfaces. I spoke to someone else who gave me the workaround (by adding the `<tr></tr>` to the top) and he said he had the same issue, which is why he knew the workaround. If it was client side adding the `<tr>` wouldn't work unless there was a selector selecting the first `<td>` of the first `<tr>` and I can assure you there isn't.

Comment: What version of richfaces are you running?

Comment: Have you checked the server response? If there is any JavaScript coming in the response you wouldn't see it on the page.